# Type mismatch. Required: (Int) → Int Found: String in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin

I am trying to Implement a function generator. It returns the function by the name given. Support three functions:

"identity" (returns its argument).
"half" (returns its argument divided by 2).
"zero" (returns 0).
If the name is unknown, return the "zero" function.

```
    fun identity(x: Int) = x
    fun half(x: Int) = x/2
    fun zero(x: Int) = 0

    fun generate(functionName: String): (Int) -> Int {
        if(functionName.isEmpty()) {
            return ::zero
        } 
            return functionName
  
    }
    fun main(){
    generate("identity")
    }
```

i am getting error:
Kotlin: Unsupported [References to variables aren't supported yet]

Comment: Are you expecting that String you passed in to magically resolve to the function with the same name? Why?

Comment: Instead of `return functionName` you need `return (::generate.javaMethod!!.declaringClass.methods.first { it.name == functionName }.let { method -> { method.invoke(null, it) as Int } })`

Comment: The error message should make it clear what the problem is: your `generate()` function is declared to return a function type — but it doesn't…

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd want something like this:

```
fun generate(functionName: String): (Int) -> Int = when(functionName) {
    "identity" -> ::identity
    "half" -> ::half
    "zero" -> ::zero
    else -> ::zero
}
```